# JAVA | Time in xd : hh:mm compare (>,<,=)

Tags: java, algorithm, date, time

I am trying to compare two time duration in `xd, hh:mm` format and determine `>` or `<` or `=`

My approach is below where I compare time var with comparetm for less than , greater than or equal and if hours provided is greater than 24 hrs I have increase days count by day

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String time ="4d, 26:00";
    String campareTm = "5d";
    String[] tokens = time.toString().split(",");
    String days =tokens[0].replace("d", "");
    String[] timeHrsMin =tokens[1].split(":");
    if (Integer.parseInt(timeHrsMin[0])>24) {

    }
    String criteria ="lt";
    switch (criteria) {
    case "lt":

        break;

    case "gt":

        break;

    case "eq":

        break;  

    default:
        break;
    }


}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html If you can have hours > 24 then I suggest you split that string into 3 parts: days, hours, minutes. Then get minutes from days and hours and add them all up. Then create a duration object from minutes and profit from its very convenient API.

Comment: working with java 1.7 so will not be able to go ahead with your  suggestion

Comment: Yes you can! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/Duration.html

Comment: still how would i compare two time var

Comment: There is `longerThan` , `shorterThan` and `compare` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to increase the day by one

```
if (Integer.parseInt(timeHrsMin[0])>=24) {
    days=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(days)+1);
}
```